# Best practice in 2013 for webpage audio.

Tags: html, audio

For a long time I've been using Soundmanager2 (http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) whenever I need to add sound to a webpage.  This is a good overall library that makes playing sounds on the web easy and straight forward.

Are there any better/more modern approaches to web sound, particularly with HTML5 audio, or is this technology still not mature enough to be useful?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 allows you to have a native audio player that is essentially supported by all the major browsers, and the advantage of HTML5 is that you can still use your soundmanager2 as what is called a "fallback". http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/